# NTFS Partition got merged in Time Machine

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, big-sur

I have an external storage drive where i had two type of partitions as NTFS and exFAT. To take backup from my macbook, i formated my exFAT and selected for the Time Machine. Then both partitions become one and the data i had in NTFS also gone. How can i get back my data in NTFS. Those are very important to me.

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         1000.0 GB  disk2s2
```

Comment: You can't use Time Machine to backup on an exFAT partition (at least not without additional tricks). Did Time Machine indicate that it will use the whole drive when you set it up? What is the result of `diskutil list` (run with the external drive mounted and then copy/paste the result into your question as text)?

Comment: @nohillside not its didnt asked to use as a whole drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the output the APFS partition created by TM uses the whole disk, the NTFS partition is gone. Depending on whether you already created a backup and other factors the data may or may not recoverable by a data recovery service.

Comment: Even though i selected one partition why did it got merged and the data been wiped out ?

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj I only can comment on the current state of your disk, not on how it got into it.